# Duplicate ServletName detected in Apache Camel blueprint based OSGi bundles

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am trying to create two Camel servlet based APIs (two OSGi bundles). I am using blueprint XML as in [this example](https://github.com/ruwanka/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-servlet-rest-blueprint).

These are the two blueprint XMLs,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
  <reference id="httpService" interface="org.osgi.service.http.HttpService"/>

  <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
        init-method="register"
        destroy-method="unregister">
    <property name="alias" value="/digital"/>
    <property name="httpService" ref="httpService"/>
    <property name="servlet" ref="teamCamelServlet"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="teamCamelServlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet"/>

  <bean id="teamService" class="com.test.TeamService"/>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

    <restConfiguration component="servlet" bindingMode="json" contextPath="/digital"
                       port="8181">
      <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
    </restConfiguration>

    <rest path="/team" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
    ..content omitted
    </rest>

  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

other `blueprint.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

  <reference id="httpService" interface="org.osgi.service.http.HttpService"/>

  <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
        init-method="register"
        destroy-method="unregister">
    <property name="alias" value="/api"/>
    <property name="httpService" ref="httpService"/>
    <property name="servlet" ref="camelServlet"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="camelServlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet"/>

  <bean id="helloService" class="com.test.HelloService"/>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

    <restConfiguration component="servlet" bindingMode="json" contextPath="/api"
                       port="8181">
      <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
    </restConfiguration>

    <!-- defines the rest services using the context-path /user -->
    <rest path="/hello" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
    ..content omitted
    </rest>

  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

But I get this error message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Duplicate ServletName detected: CamelServlet. Existing: CamelHttpTransportServlet[name=CamelServlet] This: CamelHttpTransportServlet[name=CamelServlet]. Its advised to use unique ServletName per Camel application.
```

What I am doing wrong here? I'm trying to run these two OSGi bundles in Apache ServiceMix. If one of them deployed, then it is working fine. If both deployed, only first one is working. I am new to Apache Camel and any help would be great. I've tried restarting ServiceMix, but no luck. Also tried out with clear the bundle cache.

Comment: can you add the full blueprint.xml for both bundles?

Comment: I think it might be that you've declared the port on both servlet definitions. It's better to use the pax web servlet (on the cxfservlet you just remove the port, but I'm not sure how to do this with the rest configuration component)

Comment: @stringy05 thanks, I'll look into that. By the way it is not complaining about any port binding issues.

Comment: No it never does (with versions I've used), what happens with other servlet components is that it attempts to bind, logs it if it's successful and then logs nothing if the 2nd bind fails. If you change the 2nd port to say 8182, does that work?

Answer (score 2):

When CamelHttpTransportServlet founds two servlets registering with the same name, it throws an exception "Duplicate ServletName detected...".

In the example the property "servletName" for OsgiServletRegisterer is not set up, therefore a registerer class uses the default value, which is "CamelServlet".

Still, there is something more. In the camel rest configuration should be declared additional endpoint property to provide camel an information about the servlet to use (by default it uses "CamelServlet").

So, to start two separate servlets your coufiguration should be like:

Registerer bean configuration:

```
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
      init-method="register"
      destroy-method="unregister">
    <property name="alias" value="/digital"/>
    <property name="httpService" ref="httpService"/>
    <property name="servlet" ref="teamCamelServlet"/>
    <property name="servletName" value="teamCamelServlet"/>
</bean>
```

Camel rest configuration:

```
<restConfiguration component="servlet" bindingMode="json" contextPath="/digital" port="8181">
  <endpointProperty key="servletName" value="teamCamelServlet"/>
  <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
</restConfiguration>
```

This solution should work for camel 2.14.1 and above

Version 2.14.0 contains a bug, because of which the solution does not works
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7971

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll tryout your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `OsgiServletRegisterer` uses "CamelServlet" as as default servlet-name while registering the `CamelHttpTransportServlet`.

In both the bundles it is trying to register with the default name. That is the reason you are getting said error.

Try setting different servletName in `OsgiServletRegisterer` bean as follows

```
<property name="servletName" value="helloCamelServlet"/>
```

EDIT : try some thing like this

```
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
        init-method="register"
        destroy-method="unregister">
    <property name="alias" value="/digital"/>
    <property name="httpService" ref="httpService"/>
    <property name="servlet" ref="teamCamelServlet"/>
    <property name="servletName" value="teamCamelServlet"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: I used name property as `helloServlet` then I got this issue `org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to find property descriptor helloServlet on class org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer` which seems obvious because of the [source of OsgiServletRegisterer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-servlet/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/servlet/osgi/OsgiServletRegisterer.java). Any Idea what is going on?

Comment: There is no property/variable called "helloServlet" in OsgiServletRegistere‌​r.

Comment: I've updated the code, it doesn't give the error anymore. But the endpoint is not working. I got 404, no clue in the log also.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan, did the ever resolve the final issue of the 404 error? I am trying to do the exact same thing but as soon as I set a property name on the `OsgiServletRegisterer` bean I get a 404 error.